# Save a file to database from PHP, View it from database in VB.net

Tags: php, sql, vb.net

First off, I want to say that yes, I do know that doing this with file system and just saving the file name/location in the database is the better way to go, and I will probably do that in the final version.

This is mostly an experiment/proof of concept/learning opportunity.

I have a PHP upload form **that is working**. It takes an image and turns it into a base64 string and puts it into an image blob in the database table.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    // cleaning title field
    $title = trim(sql_safe($_POST['title']));

    if ($title == '') // if title is not set
        $title = '(empty title)';// use (empty title) string

    if ($_POST['password'] != $password)  // cheking passwors
        $msg = 'Error: wrong upload password';
    else
    {
        if (isset($_FILES['photo']))
        {
            @list(, , $imtype, ) = getimagesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
            // Get image type.
            // We use @ to omit errors

            if ($imtype == 3) // cheking image type
                $ext="png";   // to use it later in HTTP headers
            elseif ($imtype == 2)
                $ext="jpeg";
            elseif ($imtype == 1)
                $ext="gif";
            else
                $msg = 'Error: unknown file format';

            if (!isset($msg)) // If there was no error
            {
            //$file = File Image yang ingin di encode 
            //Filetype: JPEG,PNG,GIF
            $base64 = "";
            $file = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
            if($fp = fopen($file,"rb", 0))
            {
                $gambar = fread($fp,filesize($file));
                fclose($fp);
                $base64 = chunk_split(base64_encode($gambar));
            }     
                // Preparing data to be used in query
            $q = "INSERT INTO tblCompanyImg (CompanyID, ImgNum, ImgExt, ImgName, ImgImg) Values (1, 1, '$ext', '$title', '$base64')";
                $database->query($q);

                $msg = "Success: image uploaded:";
            }
        }
        elseif (isset($_GET['title']))      // isset(..title) needed
            $msg = 'Error: file not loaded';// to make sure we've using
                                            // upload form, not form
                                            // for deletion
    }
}
?>
```

And I know it is saving it in correctly because I can view the image like this:

```
<?php
    while($row = $database->fetch_array($result))
    {
        $CompanyImgID = $row["CompanyImgID"];
        $CompanyID = $row["CompanyID"];
        $ImgName = $row["ImgName"];
        // outputing list
        echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . $row['ImgImg'] . "' />"; 
    }
?>
```

What I would like to do next is to view the uploaded image within a visual basic program.

I tried this:

```
    Dim sSql As String = "Select * from tblCompanyImg Where CompanyImgID = 2"
    Dim rSelect As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim img As Image
    Dim imageBytes As Byte()
    Dim ms As MemoryStream

    With rSelect
        .Open(sSql, MyCn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)
        If Not .EOF Then
            imageBytes = .Fields!ImgImg.Value
            ms = New MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length)
            ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length)
            img = Image.FromStream(ms, True) ' it fails right here: Parameter is not valid '
            LogoPictureBox.Image = img
        End If
        .Close()
    End With
```

but it fails on the `img = Image.FromStream(ms, True)` line with an error Parameter is not valid.

Is there a better way to read or write this to the database to make it work?

Comment: tip: blob fields are INTENDED for binary storage. there's no need to base64 encode it. You just increase the size of the data by ~33% and force extra processing later to decode it again.

Comment: Are you saying I can just take this: `$base64 = chunk_split(base64_encode($gambar));` and put `$base64 = chunk_split($gambar);` and have it work?

Comment: no. just `$gambar = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']))`, or whatever your DB library's equivalent function is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Why are you base 64 decoding it before hand?
- I would recommend saving the memetype on upload, making sure to sort out ie's freaky p-jpeg issues.

---

Anyway, here's a class for you.

MyImage.vb

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO

Public Class MyImage
    Implements IHttpHandler

    Public Function GetImage(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal type As String) As Byte()
        Dim Con As New SqlConnection(Common.ConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.CommandText = _
            "Select * from tblCompanyImg Where CompanyImgID = @imgID"
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = Con

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgID", id)

        Con.Open()
        Dim dReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        dReader.Read()
        Dim img As Byte()
        If dReader.HasRows Then
            img = dReader("Image")
        Else
            Dim im As New ImageManipulator
            Dim notfound = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath & "Images\404.jpg")
            img = im.ConvertImageToByteArray(notfound)
        End If

        Con.Close()

        Return img
    End Function

    Function GetMEMEType(ByVal id As Integer) As String
        Dim Con As New SqlConnection(Common.ConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.CommandText = _
            "Select * from tblCompanyImg Where CompanyImgID = @imgID"
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = Con

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgID", id)

        Con.Open()
        Dim dReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        dReader.Read()
        Dim MEME As String
        If dReader.HasRows Then
            MEME = dReader("MEMEType")
        Else
            MEME = "image/jpeg"
        End If

        Con.Close()

        Return If(MEME = "image/pjpeg", "image/jpeg", MEME)
    End Function

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable As Boolean Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As System.Web.HttpContext) Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        Dim path As String = context.Request.Path
        Dim id = path.Split(".")(0).Split("/").Last ' not very pretty, grabs the id from the filename requested
        Dim size = path.Split(".")(1) 'grabs the size required, thumb or full.

        Dim imageData As Byte() = GetImage(id, size)
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
        'context.Response.
        context.Response.ContentType = GetMEMEType(id)
        'context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=img.jpg")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then stick this in your web.config

```
<add verb="GET" path="*.jpg.db" type="project.MyImage,project"  resourceType="Unspecified" name="databaseHandler" />
```

Then calling 2.jpg.db will get your image file.

Comment: I'm kind of trying to put two exercises together. The first is all PHP based: Read file, encode it to base64, put it into the blob, and then when the web page loads read it right out of the database and put it into an img src directly without having to write it back out to the file system. That's the reason for the base64 stuff; the examples I found did it that way and I haven't found a better way that works yet. This new project doesn't have to be base64, I just figured I'd start there because I already had those images in the database, and it could be nice if they were interoperable.

Comment: Yeah it's silly - follow Marc's suggestion and just ignore it. Delete the uploaded images.